# why I cant delete any folder within /usr/local

Tags: delete

I try to delete the folder `/usr/local`, and I realized that I cant *change* the name of the folder nor I can *move* and now I cant *delete*, can someone explains me why??

Comment: Why do you need to delete a system directory? That is a really BAD idea.

Comment: you can do `sudo rm -r  -f /usr/local`  BUT DON'T DO THAT. FIRST ANSWER Pilot6's Question. Its really a bat Idea.

Comment: @VishwaPrakashHV, thanks for your reply, but I dont understand why some times its necessary to the put the `sudo`. yesterday I used the command `rm -rf xxx`, every thing work fine and why in this special case I have to use the `sudo`

Comment: @JIri - By default there are two users when you install Ubuntu - root and the other one is the username you entered during installation. So, there are some folders mostly `system` folders that are owned by `root` only. So, to access those folders or files you need to enter `sudo`.

Comment: * bad idea                      .              .                .

Comment: @VishwaPrakashHV, thanks for a great answer...good luck

Comment: @JIri I suggest you read the DESCRIPTION of `man sudo`

Answer (score 1):

## Do not remove or rename that directory!

And unless you know what you're doing, ***don't mess with items inside it***.

It is a *core system directory*, and **should not be removed**.  If it's empty, then don't worry because it's OK if it's empty - that empty directory isn't going to impinge on your disk space at all, so there is **no reason to remove it**.

Folders inside that directory are locally-installed (compiled, or locally installed by hand) programs, libraries, and dependent files which you ***should not mess with without good reason***.  Deleting files inside there, or removing the `/usr/local` folder itself can cause a LOT of headaches and problems, including breaking functionality on your system.

Comment: no I am not deleting the `/usr/local/` folder. There is folder with in this directory and I want to remove it. Why I cant remove it??

Comment: @JIri *what* directory is it?  *why* do you want to remove it?  You should **not be messing with that directory in any way, shape, or form unless you know what you are doing**.

Comment: `/usr/local/my special software folder`. I want to uninstall this software and realized that nothing happen to this `/usr/local/**my special software folder**`

Comment: @JIri then edit your question to specifically state that's what you're trying to remove - your question asks about `/usr/local` and NOT about anything inside it, so your question is incorrectly stated, and won't ever be able to be answered the way you need it to be answered.